# Convert Data to JSON format where fields are space (single or multiple) and newline separated values

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to convert space separated data to JSON format for my *react* based web app where I'm using *node* as backend but I'm unable to solve this problem as sometimes there are single space between the values and then there are time when they are separated by multiple spaces or even newline. Here is the sample data I'm trying to convert:

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I'm trying to convert it to: {created at: value, text: value, user_id: value}

Comment: what is the format used for user_id ?

Comment: user_id can contain alphabet, numbers or special character

Comment: newlines are only before dates ?

Comment: No sometime it's before the URL or user_id too.

Comment: Can a userid contain spaces? Is a userid always followed by a newline?

Comment: It can't contain space, yes it always followed by a newline.

Comment: Have you thought about using regular expressinons?

Comment: Do you have a user_id list already defined?

Comment: Is the expected result `{"created_at":"2014-06-01 23:07:58", "text":"President Resigns in Georgia’s Breakaway Region of 
Abkhazia t.co/DAploRvCvV", "user_id":"nytimes"}`?

Comment: I thought about using regex but was unable to decide how to do it with that, as I could not think for any particular pattern.

Comment: @guest271314 yes the expected result needs to be in that format.

Comment: No user_id list is not defined

Comment: _"No user_id list is not defined"_?

Comment: @guest271314 someone asked if the user_id list is already defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is code with parse your data to json where each line represente an object and object attributes are separated by space/multi space.

```
let string = `2008-06-05   text1       1
2008-06-01               text2       2`;

let regex = /([-0-9]+)\s+([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+)\b/g;

parseString = function parseString(string) {
    let obj = [];
    while (temp = regex.exec(string)) {
        obj.push({
            created_at: temp[1],
            text: temp[2],
            user_id: temp[3]
        });
    }

    return JSON.stringify(obj);
};
```

call `parseString` with the data string to get the json object

```
parseString(string);
>> "[{"created_at":"2008-06-05","text":"text1","user_id":"1"},{"created_at":"2008-06-01","text":"text2","user_id":"2"}]"
```

Answer (score 1):

There you go !

```js
let txt = document.getElementById("text").innerHTML

let reg = /\d\d\d\d-(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) (00|[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9]):([0-9]|[0-5][0-9])/g;

let arr = [];
let start = null;
let line, lastSpacePos;
while ((match = reg.exec(txt)) != null) {
    if(start) {
      line = txt.slice(start, match.index).trim();
      lastSpacePos = line.lastIndexOf(' ');
     arr.push({
   date: line.slice(0, 19),
   text: line.slice(20, lastSpacePos).trim(),
      user_id: line.slice(lastSpacePos).trim()
   });
    }
    
    start = match.index
}
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<div id="text">
2014-06-01 23:07:58 President Resigns in Georgia’s Breakaway Region of 
Abkhazia t.co/DAploRvCvV                                                    nytimes 
2014-06-01 23:48:06 The NYT FlipBoard guide to understanding climate 
change and its consequences t.co/uPGTuYiSmQ                                 nytimes 
2014-06-01 23:59:06 For all the struggles that young college grads 
face, a four-year degree has probably never been more valuable 
t.co/Gjf6wrwMsS         nytimes 
2014-06-01 23:35:09 It's better to be a community-college graduate than 
a college dropout t.co/k3CO7ClmIG                                           nytimes 
2014-06-01 22:47:04 Share your experience with Veterans Affairs health 
care t.co/PrDhLC20Bt                                                        nytimes 
2014-06-01 22:03:27 Abandon Hope, Almost All Ye Who Enter the N.B.A. 
Playoffs t.co/IQAJ5XNddR  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you understand german, this book is great:
http://openbook.rheinwerk-verlag.de/javainsel9/javainsel_04_007.htm#mj26fc5cf60311afbddd72295cdd646a48

Your reg ex should be like that (I tested it now):

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s{1}([\w\W]*?)\s{7,}(\w{7})
```

That means:

`(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})`   The date as the `group 1`. You can access each matched group separately.

`\s{1}`   Exactly one space

`([\w\W]*?)`   All kind of word and non word signs at any length, not greedy, as the `group 2`.

`\s{7, }`   7 or more spaces

`(\w{7})`   Exact 7 signs word, as `group 3`.

If your userids can have more or less signs you have to change the `(\w{7})` in for instance `(\w{6,8})` for 6 till 8 letters.

You need a MULTILINE match! That you can get with the m behind the regex: `/.../m`

```
const regexpr = /(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s{1}([\w\W]*?)\s{7,}(\w{7})/m;
```

These german sites are good as well:

https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/JavaScript/Objekte/RegExp

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Matching groups:

```
let match = 'your string'.match(/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s{1}([\w\W]*?)\s{7,}(\w{7})/m)
alert( match.length ); // 3
alert( match[0] ); // The date
alert( match[1] ); // The text
alert( match[2] ); // The userid
```

described here in english:

https://javascript.info/regexp-groups

Now you found the first match.
If you add the g the reg ex matches global, that means all matching parts.

```
let reg = /your regexp/mg;
```

You can test it with:

https://regex101.com/r/S4eTPL/4/

or

https://www.regextester.com/